# Simple Curry function

Tags: functional-programming, interview-questions, typescript

This is a interview practice question from [BFE.dev](https://bigfrontend.dev/).

> Currying is a useful technique used in JavaScript applications.
>
> Please implement a `curry()` function, which accepts a function and return a curried one.

The solution is pretty simple, but when implementing it with TypeScript the compiler will throw a warning about my usage of `this`.

```
// This is a JavaScript coding problem from BFE.dev 
function curry(fn: (...args: any[]) => any): (...args: any[]) => any {
  return function curried(...args: any[]): any {
    if (args.length >= fn.length) {
      return fn.apply(this, args);
    } else {
      return curried.bind(this, ...args);
    }
  }
}
```

The warning:

> ```
> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
> ```

So then I have two questions:

1. What should `this` be in this context?
2. How can I type `this` to be correct based on the answer to #1?

For #1 I looked at Arnav Aggarwal's "[Simple Rules to `this` in JavaScript](https://medium.com/codeburst/the-simple-rules-to-this-in-javascript-35d97f31bde3)."

> 1. If the `new` keyword is used when calling the function, `this` inside the function is a brand new object.
> 2. If `apply`, `call`, or `bind` are used to call/create a function, `this` inside the function is the object that is passed in as the argument.
> 3. If a function is called as a method, such as `obj.method()` — `this` is the object that the function is a property of.
> 4. If a function is invoked as a free function invocation, meaning it was invoked without any of the conditions present above, `this` is the global object. In a browser, it is the `window object`. If in strict mode ('use strict'), `this` will be `undefined` instead of the global object.
> 5. If multiple of the above rules apply, the rule that is higher wins and will set the `this` value.
> 6. If the function is an ES2015 arrow function, it ignores all the rules above and receives the `this` value of its surrounding scope at the time it is created.

I'm pretty sure #1 can be eliminated (probably?), but #2, #3, and #4 all seem like they could be true at runtime. So then, how can I type `this` properly?

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/287297/revisions#rev-body-d8051e86-1c54-4b23-960e-fcc9a5a3b467) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate `this` in the following way:

```js
function curry(fn: (...args: any[]) => any): (this: CallableFunction, ...args: any[]) => any {
...
```

In your context, the code is calling `apply` and `bind` on `this`. In order to do that `this` may be typed as a `CallableFunction`.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I don't really see why this was closed. The code runs exactly as intended, but gets TypeScript warnings. TypeScript has (mostly) nothing to do with actual runtime behavior.

Comment: I apologize- it wasn't obvious that it was just a warning. After going through CR meta I realize [in general code with warnings are acceptable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6524/120114) and I have updated your question to make it clear that it is a warning instead of an error.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thank you!